# Segmentation fault on most binaries without file /etc/ld.so.nohwcap

Tags: debian, debian-lenny, libraries, glib

I've got a box which was partially updated to Debian Lenny. It throws `Segmentation fault` on even simple commands like `ls`. When I added file `/etc/ld.so.nohwcap` I was able to upgrade and run machine.

Now I'd like to remove this file, but when I do this -- I got the same segmentation fault. What should I check?

```
   /etc/ld.so.nohwcap  When  this  file is present the dynamic linker will
                       load the non-optimized version of a  library,  even
                       if the CPU supports the optimized version.
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial updates or restarting interupted updates/upgrades don't work very well for any operating system.

You can look to see if rolling back to your previous configuration is available and then retry the upgrade.

But I would advise backup and then nuke & pave, i.e. a fresh install of 'Lenny'.

Comment: Yep, that's what I should do, but except this thing box seems to work...

Comment: Mmmm, wait for other things to bite you in the a**e, especially when deadlines loom? Seems like an exciting idea ;-) Seriously: reduce risk and make sure you have a clean install. You might have underlying hardware trouble or compatibility issues, and wrongly attribute them to your partial update. A clean install might turn out to be very rewarding :-)